# How to use ROW-COUNT to check whether one part pertaining more then one Source system or not?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries with the result are as follows:

```
select SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID, PARENT_PART_KEY_ID
from Master
where PARENT_PART_KEY_ID = 7619088
```

```
SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID    PARENT_PART_KEY_ID
90                  7619088
90                  7619088
90                  7619088
90                  7619088
90                  7619088
90                  7619088
90                  7619088
90                  7619088
1                   7619088
1                   7619088
90                  7619088
90                  7619088
90                  7619088
```

```
select SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID, PARENT_PART_KEY_ID
from Master
 where PARENT_PART_KEY_ID = 7369179
```

```
SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID    PARENT_PART_KEY_ID
1                   7369179
1                   7369179
1                   7369179
1                   7369179
1                   7369179
1                   7369179
1                   7369179
1                   7369179
1                   7369179
1                   7369179
1                   7369179
```

Now I want to know that if PARENT_PART_KEY_ID comes from more then one SOURCE_SYSTEM or not? so based on that I have to put condition.

so how to use row count to check whether PARENT_PART_KEY_ID pertaining to one SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID or more than one SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `count()` with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT source_system_id) number_of_sources
       FROM master
       WHERE parent_part_key_id = 7369179;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the no of pertaining sources using count(*).

```
select parent_part_key_id,count(*) from master group by parent_part_key_id
```

if wanted to fetch parent_part_key_id having only one source_system_id then it can be included in 'having' condition

```
select parent_part_key_id,count(*) from master group by parent_part_key_id having count(source_system_id)=1
```

not mandatory to use rowcount... i guess...

Answer (score 0):

Use row_count in below acceptable, but you can use best way for you... I guess this example code is usable :

```
With t
As (
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PARENT_PART_KEY_ID ORDER BY SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID ASC) 
AS Rownum, PARENT_PART_KEY_ID, SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID
FROM [master] --master is table name
Group by PARENT_PART_KEY_ID, SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID)

Select * from t --where rownum =1 --you can use 'where' for find first or end of row in you data
```

If you not want use CTE you can use select and then insert results in temp table then use them.